# Retrieving data from two related list

Tags: java

I have two list AList and BList.
Elements in AList are childs and elements in BList are parents. A child can have more than one parent. Means if element at 0th index of AList can have one than more parent in BList.
I want to retrieve data from these list in such a way that for every child I can get parents.

Suppose if 0th element is the child and it has three parents in parent list then I want to retrieve all the parents of that child.

How can I do that?

```
Child  Parent
A         2A,3A, 4A
```

And so on

Please help

Comment: What have you tried ? Is this for school or what

Comment: How does a child know who are its parents? What kind of objects are stored in the lists? Strings?

Comment: Yes there are strings

Comment: In computer slang a "parent"  has several "children" - the other way around.

Comment: List are mapped in such a way that if index 1 is a child then it's parent will also be at index 1 in parent list

Comment: Hi user, welcome to stackoverflow, we are not there to code your homeworks, please start at [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then edit your post..

For your question there is missing basic info- what have you tried, are you getting some error, or not? etc.. 
And also the good question is how the childs knows who is their parent.. Etc. Feel free to edit your post regarding the link mcve

Comment: *"List are mapped in such a way that if index 1 is a child then it's parent will also be at index 1 in parent list"* How can a child have multiple parents then?

Comment: First, please show your efforts, because this is not a school, so no one is going to spoon-feeding you.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do this is use map. In this case, Child object will be a key, and set of parents will be a value;

So you can create Set field in Child class, then create child object and add parents to their Set (you need to create Your own method that adding parents to child setOfParents - like addParents()). After all, put Child object to map as key and Set of parents as value.

For example ->

```
Map<Child, Set<Parent>> map = new HashMap();
Child a = new Child();
Parent p = new Parent();
a.addParent(p);
map.put(a, a.getListOfParents());
```

Comment: I tried using map Map<String, String>
Something like this
for(int i=0;i<child. size;i++)
map. put(child. get(i), parent. get(i))

But on retrieving not getting all the parents

Comment: To receiving data from Collections you cant use for loop - it wont work correctly. You need to use Iterator. :) But remember, that same Iterator object can be use only one time.

Comment: If possible could your please tell me to how to do it using iterator with my condition

Comment: Iterator<Parent> iterator = setOfParents.iterator();

However, probably you can try get all parents by for each loop like that:

for (Parent p : childObject.getSetOfParents){

}

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
    // given are
    List<String> a = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
    List<String> b = Arrays.asList("1A", "2A", "3A", "4B", "5B", "6C");

    // map parents and children
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    a.forEach(x -> map.put(x, new ArrayList<>()));
    b.forEach(x -> map.get(x.substring(x.length() - 1)).add(x));
```

This leads to a map with parents of children. And

```
System.out.println(map);
```

gives:

```
{A=[1A, 2A, 3A], B=[4B, 5B], C=[6C]}
```